# Natural deduction rules for $\top$

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

If we think of $\top$ as $(\neg\bot)$, we might be able to make a natural deduction rules for  $\top$ from the natural deduction  rules  of $ \neg $ and $\bot$. The following are some of the natural deduction rules of my logic book.

> axioms: $\Sigma \vdash \alpha$ iff $\alpha$ occurs in $\Sigma$
>
> FI: $\dfrac{\Sigma \vdash \alpha, \ \Sigma \vdash  (\neg\alpha) }{\Sigma \vdash ⊥}$
>
> NI: $\dfrac{\Sigma\cdot \alpha\vdash ⊥ }{\Sigma \vdash (\neg \alpha)},\quad $
> NE: $\dfrac{\Sigma\cdot  (\neg \alpha) \vdash ⊥ }{\Sigma \vdash\alpha}$

According to these rules, we can prove $\Sigma\vdash \top $ for any $\Sigma$.  So, can we think of $\Sigma\vdash \top$ as an axiom? And what should be the **$\top$-elimination** rule?

Comment: You really don't want "$\Sigma\vdash\alpha$ **iff** $\alpha$ occurs in $\Sigma$" but just an if. $\alpha$ does not need to occur in $\Sigma$ for it to be derivable.

Comment: To put this problem into perspective, the symbols $\top$ and $\bot$ are not used at all mathematical proofs. I'm puzzled as to why they are thought to be necessary or even helpful in logic

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For a structural, natural deduction presentation, the rules for $\top$ just contain $$\dfrac{}{\Sigma\vdash\top}\top\mathrm{I}$$ and that's it. There is no elimination rule. One way to see why this makes sense is that dually we want an elimination rule for $\bot$ but we certainly don't want an introduction rule. Another argument for this is that we can view $\top$ as a $0$-ary case of conjunction. For (binary) conjunction, we have an introduction rule with two premises and two elimination rules. Therefore, $\top$ should have an introduction rule with zero premises and zero elimination rules.

If we define (as is often done) $\neg\alpha$ as $\alpha\to\bot$, your **FI** rule (which I assume stands for something like "falsum introduction") is revealed to be a special case of $\to$ elimination. This rule is often called $\neg$ elimination, if $\neg$ is primitive (and especially if we can use an empty right-hand side of $\vdash$ to represent contradiction). I assume this is what **NE** is supposed to stand for, but that rule doesn't really have the appropriate form for an elimination rule. As I mentioned in an answer to an earlier question of yours, these rules are not ideally stated from a structural proof theory perspective since they combine multiple logical connectives.

We can derive the $\top$ introduction rule via the definition of $\top$ as $\neg\bot$ using your rules via: $$\dfrac{}{\dfrac{\Sigma\cdot\bot\vdash\bot}{\Sigma\vdash\top}\rlap{\mathrm{NI}}}\rlap{\mathrm{Axiom}}$$

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I have one more question, what are the more ideal rules from the perspective of structural proof theory? The system LK?

Comment: **LK** is definitely a good example for classical logic. Chapter 2 of [this](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~fp/courses/atp/handouts/atp.pdf) describes **NJ** for intuitionistic logic. It also presents a bit of discussion about some of the desirable properties we want of a proof system.

Comment: The text you linked was very helpful to me. Thank you.

Comment: I guess the $\wedge$-elim rule(s) could depend on the system - I usually think of $\wedge$-elim as $\Gamma \vdash P \wedge Q$ and $\Gamma, P, Q \vdash R$ implies $\Gamma \vdash R$.  (This is mostly from seeing Coq's system first, where each inductive proposition has exactly one elim rule.  Under Curry-Howard, this corresponds to a primitive "destructuring let" expression $\mathrm{let}~(x, y) := pairexpr~\mathrm{in}~\ldots$ instead of making the projectors into primitives.)  The analogous $\top E$: $\Gamma \vdash \top$ and $\Gamma \vdash P$ implies $\Gamma \vdash P$ which is useless.

Comment: There are indeed multiple rules that can be used. Linear logic splits $\land$ into $\otimes$, with the rules you mention, and $\&$, with rules I mention. Categorically, the categorical product is usually defined with a mapping-in property which corresponds to the rules I suggest, but it can also be defined with a mapping-out property which corresponds to the rules you give. This latter view is closer to viewing products as inductive types or as $\Sigma x:A.B$, which are each naturally defined by mapping-out properties. This is probably part of why Coq doesn't have $\eta$ for products.

Answer (score 2):

The Tautology $\top$ effectively says nothing. So, it can always be inferred from nothing.  But, from it, only other tautologies can be inferred.

It is not clear what rules this would translate into.

I would agree with your introduction rule:

$\top$-**Introduction**

$\dfrac{}{\Sigma \vdash \top}$

But for $\top$-**Elimination** ...., maybe:

$\top$-**Elimination**

$\dfrac{\Sigma \vdash \top}{\Sigma \vdash \alpha \lor \neg \alpha}$

Comment: If that second proposed $\top$-Elimination rule were valid, then for *any* $\alpha$ we could derive $\vdash\alpha$. $$\dfrac{\dfrac{}{\alpha\vdash\top}{\small\top\mathsf I}\quad\dfrac{}{\alpha\vdash\alpha}{\small\mathsf{Id}}}{\vdash\alpha}{\small\top\mathsf E}$$

Comment: @GrahamKemp Quite so, good catch! I wonder what I was thinking .... :P